# laravel form post instead of put

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my form:

```
{{ Form::model($data, array(
    'route' => array('waitingtimes.update', $data->id),
    'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer',
    'method' => 'put'
)) }}
```

When I submit the form, I got

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

though I've already set the request as `put`.

Could you help me please?

#### Edit 1

I noticed that the form html is

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8082/test/public/waitingtimes/2" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="mainInformationContrainer">
</form>
```

**It is post not put,**

#### Edit 2

The problem was because I mistyped the `route` to `rout`, but not I am getting this exception

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

this is the view:

```
{{Form::model($data, array(
'route' => array('waitingtimes.update', $data->id)
, 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer',
'method' => 'put'
))}}
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>First Time:</label>
        <div class="oneInfo">
            {{ Form::text('startTime', $value=null, array('class' => 'time ui-timepicker-input', 'id' => 'startTime', 'autocomplete' => 'off'))}}
            <span class="errorMessage">
                <?php
                echo $errors->first('startTime');
                ?>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>End Time:</label>
        <div class="oneInfo">
            {{Form::text('endTime', $value=null, array('class' => 'time ui-timepicker-input', 'id' => 'endTime'))}}
            <span class="errorMessage">
                <?php
                echo $errors->first('endTime');
                ?>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Value:</label>
        <div class="oneInfo">
            {{Form::text('value', $value=null, array())}}
            <span class="errorMessage">
                <?php
                echo $errors->first('value');
                ?>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
        <input type="button" value="Cancle" class="cancelButton"/>
    </li>
</ul>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

this is the controller `update`

```
$input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, WaitingTimes::$rules);
        if ($validation->passes()){}else{
            return Redirect::route('waitingtimes.edit')->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with(array(
                'verticalMenu'=>'none',
                'verticalMenuTab' => 'none',
                'data' => $input
            ));
        }
```

Please notice that this html blade code is used for editing the data and it is working correct when I call the edit function, and I am using it also to redirect when the user try to edit information but the validation falls

Comment: Yes, HTML forms only accept POST and GET methods, laravel checks the value of the posted `_method` property, laravel form helpers create a hidden input for this (`<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">`). It's a post request but it calls the put handler.

Comment: @undefined so why the exception happens please?

Comment: Can you also post your `Routes`?

Comment: @Unnawut it is easy `Route::resource('waitingtimes', 'WaitingtimesController');`

Comment: `Input::all()` returns an array, you are treating it as an object, `$data->id`, it's supposed to be `$data['id']`?

Comment: @undefined I know that but I must say `$data->id` because as I told you i ma using the same html to both edit and redirect after edit if the validation falls. so what should I do in the edit controller when the validation falls in order to change the array of data to an object of data? I guess here is the solution? am i right?

Comment: You can cast it to object: `(object) $data`, please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php

Comment: @undefined before i apply the cast thing, I guess laravel should have something built for that right? i mean why going with working arround while the framework alreayd has a solution. laravel should have something to redirect the request with the requested model, am i right ?

Comment: @undefined I found the solution, please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

which is

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with(array(
                'verticalMenu'=>'none',
                'verticalMenuTab' => 'none',
                'data' => $input
            ));
```

Thanks to this question 
[Laravel form model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873638/laravel-form-model-binding)

Comment: Laravel also supports [Route model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to specify the method in your form creation, add this to your Form::model array:

```
'method' => 'PUT'
```

Comment: I already did that put I forgot to put that in the question, the result is the same

Comment: So did you get the hidden field name "_method" in the form? (it's generated by laravel to spoof the method PUT)

Comment: No, I mean to check the view after you run the code, then click 'view source' on your browser to check the form element on runtime to see whether the hidden form name "_method" with value "put' is added.

Comment: there is no problem with the put or post now, i edited the question, the problem was something else, i just was typo the `rout` wrong

Comment: Good for you then, btw just a suggestion, you might wanna use {{{$errors->first('startTime')}}} for all your errors in your view instead of echo for a cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to tell your form that you will be using method `PUT`:

```
{{ Form::model($data, array(
    'route' => array('waitingtimes.update', $data->id),
    'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer',
    'method' => 'put',
)) }}
```

Note that you will still see `method = "POST"` in your form but Laravel will add a hidden field called `_method` to your form. See http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form

Comment: I already did that but it was a typo, i forgot to put that in the question, then I put it in the question but someone edited the question and removed it.