# Laravel model based form like Django

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-form

I'm a Django developper and I use Laravel since some weeks.

Do Laravel has an system of model based form like Django ?

I saw how to binding data from model ([Laravel form model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873638/laravel-form-model-binding)). However, when I use Django, **it creates automaticly the fields in the form**.

So, does it exists a way to avoid {{ Form::label }} and {{ Form::fields}} writing in Laravel form according models fields ?

Comment: Nop, you'll have to do it by hand as far as I'm aware. Although that would be nice to have, I'll give you that.

Comment: too bad, I hoped so much :(

Comment: I wish. I have dreams to make one.