# Form model binding laravel in other table

Tags: laravel

I have already tried this 
[Laravel form model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873638/laravel-form-model-binding)

but I get

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id

How can i display the details in my user_details table in the form?
I have already made the joining of the tables but  i get this error. Kindly help me please

Comment: Show related code please.

Comment: Ahh i've seen my error sir.

Comment: Here's my code.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1b2c35e660dfe1aae69a02703733d083

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3d6f294473f6e54650a4a4403dc2777e

Comment: Why are people using those 'leftjoin' i just want to learn...isn't it easier to do it the eloquent way like this `User::where('id', $id)->whereHas('user_details')->first();`