# Form Model Binding with relationship

Tags: laravel

> I already looked at this post but I can't seem to make it right:
>
> [Laravel form model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873638/laravel-form-model-binding)
>
> I get this error:
>
> https://gyazo.com/2ea7b7bb6a19d588829447ee1a92053e   I use laravel 5.2
>   for this.
>
> some screenshots:
>
> https://gyazo.com/1b2c35e660dfe1aae69a02703733d083
>   https://gyazo.com/3d6f294473f6e54650a4a4403dc2777e
>   https://gyazo.com/a59aebc7362f51f9ac27852ea032f962

Comment: This would be so much easier if you pasted the code rather than screenshotting it :D Anyway, your problem is in your `join` statement. Try specifiying table in the `where` methods. Like this: `User::where('users.id', $id)->leftJoin('user_details', 'user_details.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->first()`

Comment: Oops i forgot man It was a post.

Comment: Please don't paste code as images. External images makes this worse because when these external resources weren't available anymore the question is useless. Please correct this - otherwise it is likely that this question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

Your problem is here:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id) // Here more specifically, Laravel does not know if you mean id of users table or details table
    ->leftJoin('user_details', user_details.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->first();
```

Rewrite your `where` statement like this:

```
$user = User::where('users.id', $id)....
```

And it should work. Basically since you're joining 2 tables and they both got `id` you need to specify which `id` you want to query by.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)